# ADB Root Shell, "rm -r /storage/sdcard/some/path", Permission Denied

Tags: android, adb, root, rm

I've got a rooted phone running, have done `adb root; adb connect <phone>; adb shell;` and I am unable to `rm`, `chmod`, `chown` or in any way rid myself of some files under `/storage/sdcard1/path/this_is_to_be_deleted/some_files.foo`.

I am also unable to remove them via the file manager or terminal on the phone, even with superuser granted. WTF?

How on earth does root not have rights to `rm` anything and everything? On all the *nix systems I've used root can `rm -rf /*`, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda` or any other virtually suicidal thing it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for some ungodly reason, it was necessary to `cd /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1; chown -R media_rw:media_rw *; cd /storage/sdcard1/path; rm -r this_is_to_be_deleted;`

Explanations would be welcome!

Comment: Maybe the device is rooted, but the adb isn't running as root? Just speculating...

Answer (score 0):

Doing adb shell is not going to give you root, which is what HappyCactus is trying to say. You have to do:

```
> adb root
# _
```

If you see a hash mark, you are root.

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
> adb shell
$ su
# _
```

If that still doesn't give you a #, something is going on or your device isn't actually rooted.